# Res->Raw , File path i use "res/raw/filename.xml" but doesn't work

Tags: android

I have an XML File saved in Res->Raw , i want to get the path of this file to passed it in argument of function to parse it.

The name of XML file is families.xml , so I try this but doesn't work : "res/raw/families.xml". Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
 InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.families);
```

to get an `InputStream` to your XML, and then use [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) to parse the file :

```
 XmlPullParser xpp=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
 xpp.setInput(is,"your-encoding");
```

Another alternative would be to put it in the assets folder.

Comment: i have this function loadFamilies(String Path) i want just the path of the file and the function will parse and extract data , it's clear

Comment: @MedKhachira The raw folder no longer exists after compilation. The contents are compiled into `resources.arsc`. There is no file path.

Comment: so what is the solution to put the xml file in the .apk after compilation?

Comment: @MedKhachira The code I provided lets you retrieve the contents of the file and parse it. What else do you need?

Comment: i have a fonction called loadFamilies(String path) to extract the xml file , i will not use XmlPullParser that i mean friend i want just the path of the xml file , hope that you understand me :)

Comment: @MedKhachira You could try with `android.resource://your.package.name/raw/families` or `file:///android.resource://your.package.name/raw/families`, but if that doesn't work you will have to use the InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

`res/` is just source folder. It does not exist in final app. If you want to retrieve your file you may want to either put it in `assets` folder or use `getResources().openRawResource()`

Comment: i have this function loadFamilies(String Path) i want just the path of the file and the function will parse and extract data , it's clear

Comment: so what is the solution to put the xml file in the .apk after compilation?